# what is the correct way to select an element that has a specific id, and is part of a class

Tags: css

In my case I have a class="fusion-module rt-center" and a #modlgn-remember. How do I specify this to create a rule when #modlgn-remember is also class fusion-module rt-center?

I would think something like this, but it isn't working:

```
.fusion-module rt-center #modlgn-remember {
xxx:xx;
xxx:xx;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#modlgn-remember.fusion-module.rt-center { ... }
```

Spaces are for descendant selectors, so your original selector would select a `#modlgn-remember` element inside a `rt-center` element (missing dot here) which is inside a `.fusion-module`.

Also, consider rethinking your style rules. There can only be one element with ID `modlgn-remember` on the page, so it seems redundant to add class qualifiers to the rule.

Comment: For static pages an assigned id is sufficient, but you can have a unique element (with fixed ID) have changing class assignments. For example "expanded view" vs. "preview mode".

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain the various selectors together:

```
#modlgn-remember.fusion-module.rt-center
```

This searches for an element of `id="modlgn-remember` with a class of `fusion-module` *and* `rt-center`.

Spaces within a CSS selector implies a descendant element, so your original selector (`.fusion-module rt-center #modlgn-remember`) looks for an element of `id="modlgn-remember"` that's within a `rt-center`element, that's within an element of `class="modlgn-remember"`.

Obviously, then, your original selector was unlikely to return the element you were looking for.

Remember, of course, that an `id` is unique within the document; therefore if you only want to get the element of that particular `id` you need only *use* the `id`. The only reason it makes sense to couple an `id` selector with a class-selector is to select that `id` *only if* it *also* has those classes. This is often useful in JavaScript, especially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#modlbn-remember.fusion-module.rt-center {
   ...
}
```

Selects element with that id and both classes must be assigned.

If you like to select it, if at least one of them is assigned use:

```
#modlbn-remember.fusion-module,
#modlbn-remember.rt-center {
   ...
}
```